# How to evaluate $\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x\ln \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\:dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How can i evaluate $$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x\ln \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\:dx$$
I started like this
$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x\ln \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\:dx=\frac{x^2\ln \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)}{2}|^{\frac{\pi }{2}}_0-\frac{1}{2}\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}x^2\cot \left(x\right)\:dx$$
but this way doesnt turn things any simpler, i also tried using the substitution $t=\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ and got this,
$$4\int _0^{1}\arctan \left(t\right)\ln \left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)\:\frac{1}{1+t^2}\:dt$$
$$=4\ln \left(2\right)\int _0^{1}\frac{\arctan \left(t\right)}{1+t^2}\:dt+4\int _0^{1}\frac{\arctan \left(t\right)\ln \left(t\right)}{1+t^2}\:dt-4\int _0^{1}\frac{\arctan \left(t\right)\ln \left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2}\:dt$$
That first integral is very simple but the rest look very difficult, could you help me evaluate this one?

Comment: Is the integral converging (at 0)?

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, the answer involves $\zeta(3)$, So it is not quite an easy thing to find the integral exactly.

Comment: Use the fourier series of ln(sinx) and I think this integral is possible duplicate.

Comment: The $x$ complicates matters. Without it, $\displaystyle \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\sin x) dx$ is easy to find.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон no need to be so unkind.

Comment: @maurijim I saw nothing unkind in what he wrote. Wolfram Alpha should always be the first place you check if an integral looks difficult. And you haven't given much context for this problem - where did it come from?

Comment: @Deepak no i get that and i agree but that last part what just uncalled for. Me and my classmates came up with this integral after solving a similar case.

Comment: @maurijim I apologize, it was not my intention.  The point was, after insertion into Wolfram Alpha I spotted $\zeta(3)$, the Apery constant which doesn't have easy integral representations. I guessed that you will not know this , and therefore reported that the question may be out of reach. As the answer below shows,  it is not easy, but I was rash in stating this. Sorry once again. You can ask for an explanation if you don't understand some of the steps below.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3745615/evaluate-int-01-arctan3-x-dx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}x\ln(\sin x)dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}x\left(-\ln2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2nx)}{n}\right)dx$$

$$=-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cos(2nx)dx$$

$$=-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\cos(n\pi)}{4n^2}+\frac{\pi\sin(n\pi)}{4n}-\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)$$

$$=-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{4n^2}+\frac{0}{4n}-\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)$$

$$=-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln2-\frac14\text{Li}_3(-1)+\frac14\zeta(3)$$

$$=-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln2+\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)$$

---

Bonus: With subbing $x\to \pi/2-x$ we have

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}x\ln(\cos x)dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}(\pi/2-x)\ln(\sin x)dx$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x)dx-\int_0^{\pi/2}x\ln(\sin x)dx$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2\right)-\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln2+\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)\right)$$
$$=-\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln(2)-\frac7{16}\zeta(3)$$

Or we can use the Fourier series of $\ \ln(\cos x)=-\ln2-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cos(2nx)}{n}$.

Also by subtracting the two integrals gives

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}x\ln(\tan x)dx=\frac78\zeta(3)$$

Or we can use the Fourier series of $\ \ln(\tan x)=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos((4n-2)x)}{2n-1}.$

Comment: Thanks! the solution was neat and easier than expected though i have one question ¿what were the conditions that were met that made the usage of  the fourier series possible/valid?

Comment: You welcome. It holds for x between zero and pi.

Comment: That last result is absolutely amazing, because I just see it beautifully capturing $\zeta(3)$ in integral form. This question has been nice to work on, +1 for both q and a.

Comment: @астон вілла тереса лисбон thank you. Glad you like it :)

Answer (score 3):

Define on $[0;\infty[$ the function $R$ by,

for all $x\in [0;\infty[$, $\displaystyle \text{R}(x)=\int_0^x \dfrac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln(tx)}{1+t^2x^2}\,dt$.

Observe that $\text{R}(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow}\text{R}(x)=0$
\begin{align}
 A_2&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}t\ln(\cos t)\,dt\\
 B_2&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}t\ln(\sin t)\,dt\\
 A_2+B_2&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}t\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin(2t)\right)\,dt\\
 &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}t\ln\left(\sin(2t)\right)\,dt-\frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{8}\\
 &\overset{x=2t}=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\pi x\ln(\sin x)\,dx-\frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{8}\\
 &\overset{t=\pi-x}=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\pi (\pi-x)\ln(\sin x)\,dx-\frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{8}\\
 2(A_2+B_2)&=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin x)\,dx-\frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{4}\\
 A_2+B_2&=\frac{\pi}{8}\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin x)\,dx-\frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{8}\\
 &=-\frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{4}\\
 B2-A2&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}t\ln(\tan t)\,dt\\
 &\overset{x=\tan t}=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
 U_2&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
 V_2&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan\left(x\right)\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
 U_2+V_2&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
 &=0\\
 U_2&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\left[R(x)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]_0^\infty +\int_0^\infty \frac{R(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
 &=\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln(tx)}{(1+t^2x^2)(1+x^2)}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
 &=\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^1 \dfrac{x\ln(x)}{(1+t^2x^2)(1+x^2)}\,dt\right)\,dx+\\
 &\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x\ln(t)}{(1+t^2x^2)(1+x^2)}\,dx\right)\,dt\\
 &=V_2+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{t^2-1}\,dt\\
 &=V_2+\int_0^1 \frac{t\ln^2 t}{1-t^2}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
 &\overset{u=t^2}=B+\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
 &=V_2-\frac{7}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
 &=V_2-\frac{7}{8}\times 2\zeta(3)\\
 &=V_2-\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)\\
 U_2&=-\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)\\
 V_2&=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)\\
 B_2-A_2&=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)\\
 A_2&=-\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{8}\pi^2\ln 2\\
 B_2&=\boxed{\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{8}\pi^2\ln 2}\\
\end{align}

NB: I assume following results:
\begin{align}
 \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx&=0\\
 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx&=2\zeta(3)\\
 \int_0^\pi \ln(\sin x)\,dx&=-\pi\ln 2
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

**An incomplete solution requiring some more interesting work:**

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} x \ln (\sin x) dx= \int_{0}^{1} \ln t ~\frac{\sin^{-1} t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt.$$
Using the MacLaurin series for $$\frac{\sin^{-1} t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} t^{2n+1}$$

See:
[Deriving Maclaurin series for $\frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549028/deriving-maclaurin-series-for-frac-arcsin-x-sqrt1-x2)
Then
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1}\ln t ~\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} t^{2n+1}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}~ \int_{0}^{\infty}u~e^{-(2n+2)u}~du~~( t=e^{-u})$$
$$\implies I=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} \frac{1}{(2n+2)^2}$$
I have numerically confirmed using Mathematica that $I$ is nothing but
$$\frac{1}{16}[-\pi^2 \ln 4+7 \zeta(3)]$$
The same as obrained @Ali Shather in his very nice solution above.
Can some one fill the gap here! I may come back.

Comment: you can find some nice identities here https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Reihenentwicklungen#Potenzen_des_Arkussinus that could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you could enjoy polylogarithms, the antiderivative does exist (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx+*+Log%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5D%2Cx%5D))
$$I=\int x\log \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\:dx$$ Using the bounds, the results are

- at $\frac \pi 2$, $\frac{1}{48} \left(9 \zeta (3)+i \pi ^3-6 \pi ^2 \log (2)\right)$
- at $0$, $\frac{1}{48} \left(i \pi ^3-12 \zeta (3) \right)$

and, then, the result.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on Cauchy's integral theorem.

Integrate
\begin{equation*}
 f(z) = \log(z)\dfrac{\log(1-z^2)}{z}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
 \log(z)=\ln|z|+i\arg(z), \qquad -\pi<\arg(z)<\pi,
\end{equation*}
over the boundary $\gamma$ of the unit circle in the first quadrant. Let $\gamma = \gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3$. Here
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\gamma_1(x)&=x,\, 0\le x\le 1\\
\gamma_2(t)&=e^{it}, \, 0 \le t \le {\pi}/2\\
\gamma_3(y)&=iy,\, y \mbox{ from } 1 \mbox{ to } 0.
\end{alignat*}
From Cauchy's integral theorem we get
\begin{gather*}
 0 =  \int_{\gamma_1}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z +  \int_{\gamma_2}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z + \int_{\gamma_3}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=\\[2ex]
 \int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)\dfrac{\log(1-x^2)}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x+
 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(e^{it})\dfrac{\log(1-e^{i2t})}{e^{it}}ie^{it} \,\mathrm{d}t-
 \int_{0}^{1}\log(iy)\dfrac{\log(1+y^2)}{iy}i\, \mathrm{d}y=\\[2ex]
  \int_{0}^{1}\ln(x)\dfrac{\log(1-x^2)}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x+
  \int_{0}^{\pi/2}i^2t\left(\ln(2\sin(t))+i\arg\left(1-e^{i2t}\right)\right)\,\mathrm{d}t-\\[2ex]
   \int_{0}^{1}\left(\ln(y)+i\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\dfrac{\log(1+y^2)}{y}\, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{gather*}
We extract the real part of every integral.
\begin{gather*}
0 = -\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{2k-1}\ln(x)}{k}\right)\, \mathrm{d}x -
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}t\ln(2)\, \mathrm{d}t -\int_{0}^{\pi/2}t\ln(\sin(t))\, \mathrm{d}t-\\[2ex]
-\int_{0}^{1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{y^{2k-1}\ln(y)}{k}\right)\, \mathrm{d}y =\\[2ex]
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{4k^3}-\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}\ln(2) -\int_{0}^{\pi/2}t\ln(\sin(t))\, \mathrm{d}t +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4k^3}=\\[2ex]
\dfrac{1}{4}\zeta(3) -\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}\ln(2) -\int_{0}^{\pi/2}t\ln(\sin(t))\, \mathrm{d}t + \dfrac{3}{16}\zeta(3).
\end{gather*}
Consequently
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{0}^{\pi/2}t\ln(\sin(t))\, \mathrm{d}t = \dfrac{7}{16}\zeta(3)-\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}\ln(2).
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 1):

Using the trapezioidal rule like numerical integration:

$$\displaystyle{\int \limits _{1}^{\frac \pi2}x\ln(\sin (x))\,dx\approx \frac{1}{2}h\left(f(1)+f\left(\frac\pi2\right)\right)=-0.03672410\\h=\frac \pi2-1}$$

I think that this is a short way to find the value of the $ \int \limits _{1}^{\frac \pi2}x\ln(\sin (x))\,dx$.